# How to enable multiple virtual consoles on linux?

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, console

I'm new to linux so I have no clue how to do this (couldn't find it on the web). I'm running a LAMP Virtual Machine and when I press ALT-F2, F3 etc.. to use a Virtual Console I get a blank screen (all black to be exact) not a login option, so the question is how can I enable multiple consoles for my system?

The linux I'm running is this [LAMP Virtual Appliances](http://virtualappliances.net/documentation/readme/README.lamp.html), Linux lamp 2.6.24-18-virtual (It says Ubuntu but I don't know the version).

I don't know if this helps but I can connect by SSH from the host computer.

Thank you,
Rodrigo.

Comment: Readers may also be interested in this [BusyBox tutorial I've created](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/58face41ac849d029536a3c0dba33c8d68c30afa#tty).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with that virtual appliance but given the kernel version, it seems like it is based on a 8.04 version of Ubuntu.  It is probably using [upstart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart).  So you probably need to create files in /etc/event.d for each virtual console you want.  You probably already have a file /etc/event.d/tty1 that you could copy to /etc/event.d/tty[2-6].  You'll need tweak the **exec** line for each file.

Of course you could also simply use [GNU Screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) and get a similar effect with additional features like being able to disconnect and then reconnect remotely.

Comment: Thank you, everything was as you said, now works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

See `man inittab` (or `/etc/inittab`). You want to ensure that `getty` is installed

```
apt-get install (util-linux|mingetty|ngetty|rungetty)
```

and ensure that the /etc/inittab file has them running for your default runlevel. E.g.:

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1
2:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty2
3:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty3
4:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty4
5:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty5
6:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty6
```

Comment: If the system is Ubuntu based as I suspect this does probably does not apply since init is not used.

Comment: Ah, true. I didn't realize that, thank you.

Comment: With busybox you need something like: `console::respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty2
console::respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty3
`

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem today, though instead of black screen when pressing alt+f2..12 it simply did nothing. I found the solution/answer on Wikipedia.

`screen` was not installed, so this was no option. I could however use the following command:

```
    openvt
```

Then to switch to the newly created Virtual Terminal, I could simply press alt+f2. Another openvt enabled alt+f3, etc. In case the alt+f1..12 keys doesn't work, use `chvt n`, where n is the virtual terminal you want to switch to (example: `chvt 1`). Using an invalid number, for example 3 when allocating only 2, gave a black screen for me. To switch back I could use alt+f1.

If you want to disallocate a virtual terminal, use `deallocvt n`, where n is the virtual terminal to disallocate. For some reason this always gives me "Device or resource busy" though.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console

Comment: Excellent tip. Thank you. (in 2020) You need to `exit` the session on `Alt+F9` to be able to `deallocvt 9`.

Answer (score 0):

The others have answered how to enable multiple TTYs. Just one more option: you can use [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) to have multiple logins and switch between them, even if you have only one tty.